# Date formats and localization

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have a scenario in which I have a form where users have to enter a date.

**In Chrome and Edge**

In these browsers you can use `<input type="date">` which displays a nice date picker using the localised date format and then would insert the date into a database in the accepted format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

**In older browsers (IE/Firefox etc)**

In these browser `<input type="date">` is not fully supported so in many cases the field defaults to a string. In this scenario I know you can use the JQuery UI Datepicker element and set the default format.

**The dilemma**

When retrieving a date from the database and placing it back into a form field it will generally be displayed as `yyyy-mm-dd` as that's how it exists in the database.

I know I could do something like this:

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y')` which would give me the UK date.

However, if I'm in IE and the field now reads `dd-mm-yyyy` if I resubmit this form it breaks the date as IE takes this format exactly as is but only accepts the original format.

**The question itself**

So, essentially is there a way to display the UK date format coming in and out of the database which is compliant in all browsers?

**My thoughts**

I was thinking about just switching back and forth between formats depending on whether the user was in IE.

In other words if the date in the field is `dd-mm-yyyy` grab it break it apart and reform it for IE browsers which I would detect using Modernizer.